# What does "git mergetool" do, and what is the job of the mergetool selected. who's responsible for auto-merge and file cleanup?

Tags: git, merge

When I have conflicts I will use "git mergetool" to help merge them.  However, What happens when I do this seems to vary depending on my environment, or perhaps the mergetool; and I'm a little surprised how much it seems varies by mergetool.

Sometimes mergetool will auto-merge most/all of the changes when I run my mergetool, with the tool simply saying that file X was automerged and possibly letting me see the merged file to verify it; with only a few files requiring me to make merge decisions.  Other times I seem to be prompted for even easily merged issues like updating a version number in a pom.

Sometimes when doing merges I see the <<<<<< HEAD and <<<<<< REMOTE syntax, other times the merge tool will show a more visually appealing syntax.

Sometimes I get .orig or .remote files left over after running mergetool and merging, other times they seem to get cleaned up and removed.

I'm trying to figure out why there is such a variance.  Does git leave the mergetools to do all of this?  When I select a merge tool am I selecting not just a way of visualizing conflicts, but also a means of auto-merging and cleaning up files afterwards?  or are these steps configured differently?  Can I get the degree of auto-merging tortuous svn use to offer me while visualizing conflicts with another tool, for instance?

And most relevant based off of that, if I'm in linux world how do I get a tool that will auto-merge obvious changes without my intervention, which none of the mergetools I've played with yet (such as meld) seem to do, do I need to hunt down a specific tool or can this be configured separately?

Comment: *Does git leave the mergetools to do all of this?* Pretty much, yes.  The only file name extensions `git mergetool` itself leaves behind are the `.orig` files.

Comment: Resolving a Git merge by hand is really not that hard, and sometimes can even be more informative than using a spoon-fed tool.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen when you make heavy use of branched development the number of trivial merge conflicts starts to go up significantly.  it can be time consuming; enough to discourage people from branching as they should.  While doable I don't want to spend the time if I can avoid it.

Comment: There is no "avoiding it" AFAIK.  The tool might make the resolution easier in certain instances but I don't see how it can prevent conflicts from happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And most relevant based off of that, if I'm in linux world how do I get a tool that will auto-merge obvious changes without my intervention, which none of the mergetools I've played with yet (such as meld) seem to do

Actually, with Git 2.29 (Q4 2020), the 'meld' backend of the "[`git mergetool`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/4aff18a3f02fece0d758427294907e7a80aa6bff/Documentation/git-mergetool.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-mergetool))</sup> learned to give the underlying '`meld`' the '`--auto-merge`' option, which would help reduce the amount of text that requires manual merging.

See [commit dbd8c09](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dbd8c09bfe9d783ae01121bafb26a2dd108c0c3f) (07 May 2020) by [Lin Sun (`sunlin7`)](https://github.com/sunlin7).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 4aff18a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4aff18a3f02fece0d758427294907e7a80aa6bff), 22 Sep 2020)</sup>

> ### [`mergetool`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dbd8c09bfe9d783ae01121bafb26a2dd108c0c3f): allow `auto-merge` for `meld` to follow the `vim-diff` behavior
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: David Aguilar</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Lin Sun</sup>

> Make the `mergetool` used with "`meld`" backend behave similarly to "`vimdiff`" by telling it to auto-merge non-conflicting parts and highlight the conflicting parts when `mergetool.meld.useAutoMerge` is configured with `true`, or `auto` for detecting the `--auto-merge` option automatically.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/dbd8c09bfe9d783ae01121bafb26a2dd108c0c3f/Documentation/config/mergetool.txt#L33-L42):

> ### `mergetool.meld.useAutoMerge`
>
> When the `--auto-merge` is given, meld will merge all non-conflicting
> parts automatically, highlight the conflicting parts and wait for
> user decision.  Setting `mergetool.meld.useAutoMerge` to `true` tells
> Git to unconditionally use the `--auto-merge` option with `meld`.
> Setting this value to `auto` makes git detect whether `--auto-merge`
> is supported and will only use `--auto-merge` when available.  A
> value of `false` avoids using `--auto-merge` altogether, and is the
> default value.